# Change Outgoing SMTP port in Exchange 2003 with a slight twist

Tags: smtp, exchange-2003

I feel like I should know this, but its been a long week already.

I have a customer with an SBS Exchange server on their LAN. They currently have their MX going to Postini, who is then delivering the mail to the Exchange box. Postini currently will only deliver on port 25, this is not adjustable.

I have a single traveling user that has the need for POP/SMTP connectivity (Outlook and Blackberry), but only has success about 50% of the time due to individual ISPs policy to block or allow port 25 traffic. Changing the Inbound port on the SMTP Virtual connector obviously breaks Postini delivery, but allows user access. So, in short, that one user can send and receive, but all external mail sent to the domain is spooled until port 25 is available again. Is there any way for this user to connect w/o using a VPN to this server on an alternate port?

Changing the Outbound port in System Manager is only when Exchange itself is delivering, and not for client connectivity, this is correct, right?

I know that a VPN would be the solution for Outlook, but not the BB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add another SMTP Virtual Server on a different port (587 is the standard for MSA anyway, users aren't supposed to send via Port 25). If you're setting up a MSA port, it's standard practice to allow only authenticated connections, and double check that there aren't any relaying oddities).